# Quotient group acts on quotient space?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

A variant of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528663/288227), leaving out the hypothesis of a faithful action.

Let $G$ be a group acting on a topological space $X$, and $N$ a normal and abelian subgroup of $G$. 
Does the action of $G$ on $X$ induce an action of the quotient group $G/N$ on the quotient space $X/N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The induced action makes the coset of $g$ map the orbit of $x$ to the orbit of $gx$.

That is: if $[x] = \{nx\mid n\in N\}$, then we let $(gN)[x] = [gx]$.

To verify that this is well defined, first note that if $[x]=[y]$ and $g\in G$, then there exists $n\in N$ such that $x=ny$. Then $gx = gny$. But since $N$ is normal, $gN=Ng$, so there exists $n’\in N$ such that $gn=n’g$. Therefore, $gny = n’gy$. Therefore,  $[gx]=[gy]$.

And second, if $gN=hN=Nh$, then there exists $n\in N$ such that $g=nh$. Therefore, $gx = nhx$, so $[gx]=[hx]$. Thus, $(gN)[x] = [gx]=[hx] = (hN)[x]$ as required.

Finally, this is indeed an action: $eN[x] = [ex] = [x]$ and $((gN)(hN))[x] = (gh)N[x] = [(gh)x] = [g(hx)] = gN[hx] = (gN)(hN[x])$.

Note that you do not need $N$ to be abelian, just normal.

Comment: What about $G/N$ acting on $X$, doesn't $(gN)(x)=g(x)$ also define a well defined action on $X$?

Comment: @monoidaltransform: Not in general, since if $nx\neq x$ for some $n\in N$, then $(gn)N=gN$, but $(gn)x\neq g(x)$, so your formula does not give a well-defined action.