# Quotient group and space action

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

If $H$ is a group acting on $X$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $H$, does it follow that $\frac{H}{N}$ acts on $X$ in the natural way?  Isn't $hN(x)=h(x)$ well defined?

My friend says yes, but I'm not sure it is:

if $hN=h'N$ then there is no reason for $h(x)=h'(x)$ for all $x$ unless $N=$id.

Comment: You're right, you generally can't deduce any action of $H/N$ on $X$ from the $H$-action, unless the elements of $N$ act trivially on $X$, essentially exactly for the reason you mention.

Comment: Why should it make any difference? And have you looked at a single example before asking?

Comment: You asked me essentially this [in this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529088/quotient-group-acts-on-quotient-space/3529109?noredirect=1#comment10228340_3529109), posted four minutes before posting this question. So you basically asked and didn't wait before posting. At least one of the two (comment or post) is superfluous.

Comment: You don't need $N$ to be trivial. You just need $N$ to *act* trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $(hN)\cdot x= h\cdot x$ is well defined if and only if $n\cdot x=x$ for all $n\in N$ and $x\in X$.

If this occurs, then if $gN=hN$, there exists $n\in N$ such that $g=hn$. Then $g\cdot x = (hn)\cdot x = h\cdot(n\cdot x) = h\cdot x$, so the formula yields a well-defined function. That it is an action now follows.

Conversely, if there exists $n\in N$ and $x\in X$ such that $n\cdot x\neq x$, then the formula does not yield a well-defined action, since $eN=nN$, but $e\cdot x = x \neq n\cdot x$.